# To create services for $http.get,

Tags: angularjs, service, typeahead

This was written in controller to get the location name using typeahead when i start typing which is working

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
        return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
            params: {
                address: val,
                // sensor: false
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data.results.map(function(item) {
                return {
                    loc: item.geometry.location,
                    formatted_address: item.formatted_address,
                    place_id: item.place_id
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

So i tried to put the $http.get to services so i added the below code to controller

```
$scope.getLocation = function(value) {
        var values = value;
        MapService.getMapUrl(values).then(function(response) {
            return response.data.results.map(function(item) {
                $scope.address=item.formatted_address;
                console.log(item.formatted_address);
                return {
                    loc: item.geometry.location,
                    formatted_address: item.formatted_address,
                    place_id: item.place_id
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

and the following code to services

```
app.service('MapService', function($http) {
return {
    getMapUrl: function(val) {
        return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
            params: {
                address: val,
                // sensor: false
            }
        })
    }
}
});
```

After creating services as above, i am getting the location in console, but not in dropdown of the input box. can anyone tell me what is the mistake in my code.

Comment: Why did you remove the place_id? What does the browser console say? Do you have any demo?

Comment: The console says what?

Comment: The console says this when i type `s`. I need this to be displayed as a dropdown in input box. `pin.js:85 Cantabria, Spain
pin.js:85 S, West Virginia, USA
pin.js:85 s, 119 S Main St, Enterprise, AL 36330, USA
pin.js:85 South, Odessa, TX 79763, USA
pin.js:85 S, Richfield, KS 67953, USA
pin.js:85 S, Big Lake, TX 76932, USA
pin.js:85 s, 87030 Marzi CS, Italy
pin.js:85 Calle S, Caborca, Son., Mexico
pin.js:85 S, Yemen
pin.js:85 s, Lima 15084, Peru`
i don't have enough previlages to upload screenshot of what i am getting. so i copy pasted it

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/yQgziHFt6aUviXkmD3wh?p=preview
this is the incomplete code plunker. can you please check with this?

Comment: Open your console: it says: "module myApp is unavailable". You haven't defined the module anywhere. The angular application doesn't even exist.

Comment: i have updated the plunker now. please check it is asking for some typeahead.html file in console. can you check now

Comment: Actually, i want like ,this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4PwaFaeIOeIDRCsvuidn?p=preview

Comment: In the first plunker, i am getting data in console. not as dropdown. but used as service. 
in the second plunker, i am getting my expected result, but not used as services. directly used in controller

Comment: Your first plunkr now displays this error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found). Fix the errors.

Comment: Use ui-bootstrap-tpls.js instead of ui-bootstrap.js. The templates are bundled in that JS file. It took 12 comments until I can finally understand that this is the error you are asking about. That's theerror I expected you to give when asking "what does the browser console say?". Error messages are **crucial** to know why an erro happens. Why didn't you post it from the start, or when I asked?

Comment: thank you so much for your time and patience. but it didn't works. no errors in the console. but i am not getting the expected result. i have updated in the same plunker. please check . sorry you were asking for the error stack. but i thought you were asking for the console result. which i was getting through `console.log`

Comment: Replace `MapService.getMapUrl(...` by `return MapService.getMapUrl(...`. Your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: thank you so much. it works . through this i got to know, templates are stored in ui-bootstrap-tpls.js.  thank you